# How can a stateless component prop function run when it renders?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a long list of items and when they render, I want the scroll to move to the bottom of the list -- but only when they render. Does anyone know how to do this with a stateless component? I would like a function to run as a prop on the component and I want this function to pass the element so that in my container component with the Redux API I can scroll to the element. However, I only want the function to run when the component renders, and I am struggling to get a function on a component to run when it renders with itself passed as an argument.

I am familiar with these events in a class component regarding the lifecycle of a component:

- componentWillReceiveProps()
- shouldComponentUpdate()
- componentWillUpdate()
- componentDidUpdate()
- render()

But these lifecycle events are not available to me in a stateless component.

Comment: Stateless function components do not have a lifecycle.

Comment: So you have a container component with seperate item components? Does the item component have a scrollTo method or how exactly do you mean?

Comment: @dejakob let's say I have a Comments container and a Comments component. The Comments component receives the comments collection from its Comments container and for each comment calls the Comment container which calls a comment component, having passed the state the comment component needs from Redux. When the list of comments is finished rendering I would like the UI to scrollTo the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Stateless function components do not have a lifecycle as that would be nonsensical. The React lifecycle is inherently stateful.

You've got a few options:

1. Convert your stateless function components to class components to make use of the lifecycle methods.
2. Wrap your stateless function components in a higher order component that provides the lifecycle management you need. Take a look at [`recompose`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) and the [`lifecycle`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle) higher order component it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment, you could solve your use case like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/83446/

In the list component, you add this in the componentWillMount:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (!this.props.comments.length && newProps.comments.length) {

      // Using setTimeout 0 will cause the function to be triggered after the re-render
      setTimeout(() => {

        // this.list being a ref on the list component 
        const { height } = this.list.getBoundingClientRect();
        document.body.scrollTop = height;
      }, 0);
    }
  }
```

In this case the Comment component can be stateless

```
function Comment(props) {
  return (
    <li>{props.comment.content}</li>
  );
}
```